# Change first child default selected color back to unfocused color

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to create a simple selection menu with css.

I want it to be like so:

upon entering page, there are list-items. The first child of the list item has a default color of yellow **(selected color)** while it's siblings have a color of blue **(unselected colors)**. I want it to where when the user clicks on the 2nd or 3rd or 4th etc.. the first child that was yellow goes back to unselected blue while the other selected list item that was selected gets changed to yellow.

I got it to where it focuses on the list colors to change color as well as the first child to change to default yellow. However, when I change to select a list item, the first-child stays yellow while the next list item that I select goes to yellow.

Here is my code I'm using Sass.

```css
  .col-md-4 {
    .trackContainer {
      color: $pColor;
      .fas {
        float: right;
      }
      .trackName {
        cursor: pointer;
        &:nth-child(odd) {
          background: #201f1d;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
          &:hover {
            background: #1d1c1a;
          }
        }
        &:nth-child(even) {
          background: #201b1d;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
          &:hover {
            background: #161314;
          }
        }
        &:first-child {
          color: $signalYellow;
        }
      }
      ol {
        li {
          @include pStyle();
          padding: 20px;
          line-height: inherit;
          outline: 0;
          &:hover {
            color: $hoverColor;
          }
          &:focus {
            color: $signalYellow;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div className="trackContainer">
    <ol>
        { this.state.trackData.map((rows, index) => (
            <div className="trackName data-tip-right"
                 data-tip={"View " + rows.trackName}
                 key={rows.trackName + "-" + rows.track_music_id}
                 onClick={e => this.showLyrics(index, rows.trackLyrics)}>
                <li tabIndex={index}>
                    {index + 1 + ". " + rows.trackName}
                    <i className="fas fa-arrow-right" />
                </li>
            </div>
        )) }
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably an issue with your function showLyrics();  You probably need to loop through all of your Tracks to unset them if they do not equal the right index, not just set the one that does.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just give the specific element an selected class and remove the class of the previous selected?

```
<ol>
 <li onmouseover="selectItem(this)">
     123
 </li >
 <li onmouseover="selectItem(this)">
     1234
 </li >
</ol>

<script>
   function selectItem(item) {
    $('.selectedItem').attr('class', '');
    $(item).attr('class', 'selectedItem');
   }
</script>

.selectedItem {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you i didnt think of that. I'm unfortunately using React and not vanilla JS. I'll see about adding that selected class thats probably a better approach. Thank you! I'll get back to you on this once I figure it out.